# MLE of generalized normal distribution

Tags: r, mle

I got warning message in R after running below code( mle of generalized normal distribution) which is given at end. My question are

Why these warnings came? How can we solve these warnings?
My code in object "result" may be little wrong?

```
library(AdequacyModel)

# New generalized exponential

data1 <- rnorm(1000)

Phi<- pnorm
phi<-dnorm

pdf_exps <- function(par,x){
beta = par[1]
gamma= par[2]
mean = par[3]
sd = par[4]
         ( beta*gamma* (1-(1-(Phi(x,mean,sd)))^beta)^(gamma-1) * (1- 
         (Phi(x,mean,sd)))^(beta-1)* phi(x,mean,sd) )
}


 cdf_exps <- function(par,x){
 beta = par[1]
 gamma= par[2]
 mean = par[3]
 sd = par[4]
  ( (1-(1-(Phi(x,mean,sd)))^beta)^gamma )
  }



  result = goodness.fit(pdf = pdf_exps, cdf = cdf_exps,
  starts = c(1,1,1,1),data =data1  , method = "BFGS",
   domain = c(-Inf,Inf), lim_inf = c(0,0,0,0),
   lim_sup = c(2,2,2,2), S = 250, prop=0.1, N=50)
   result$mle

       There were 33 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
       result$mle
       [1]  0.49952916  0.61402586 -0.07688582
       [4]  0.70616246
       warnings()
       Warning messages:
       1: In log(pdf(par, x)) : NaNs produced
       2: In log(pdf(par, x)) : NaNs produced
```

Comment: You are trying to compute the logarithm of one or more zeros (or negative values).

Comment: @RuiBarradas! I got this error for same data but with addition of one more parameter:  Error in optim(par = starts, fn = likelihood, x = data, method = "BFGS",  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [2]

Comment: That error comes from function `goodness.fit`. If you type just the function name at an R prompt you will get its source code, the error is in line 63. The function is complicated, I suggest you contact the package maintainer, `maintainer("AdequacyModel")`.